# apply value of this class to all classes of same name

Tags: jquery

I have a loop to generate letters to people.

The letter is editable. I want to apply the changed text to all columns with the same class

So if I change column 1 `.col-1` of the first letter, I want to apply the change to all of the other peoples letters ( all `.col-1` classes )

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
$(this '.col-1').on('change', function(){
    $('.col-1').val($(this '.col-1').val())
})
```

This is most likely WAY OFF, but please if you can guide me.

**UPDATE**

```
        $( ".container" ).on( "keyup", this, function( e ) {
            console.log(e.target.textContent);
            var value = e.target.textContent;
            $('.col-1').val(value);
        } );
```

I get the value in the Console, but it does not apply the value to all the textareas with class '.col-1'

**CODE**

```
<?=
    $id_cnt = 0;
    foreach($members as $key => $value){
        $id_cnt+=1;
?>

        <div id='textarea<?=$id_cnt?>' contenteditable class="col-1">At our AGM on <?=$meeting?>, members voted in favour of the membership fee to remain at the cost of <?=$amount?> for those who wish to be members of the Association.</div>


<?= } ?>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
        $( ".container .col-1" ).on( "keyup", this, function( e ) {
            var value = e.target.textContent;
            $('.col-1').not($(this)).text(value);
        } );
```

Comment: I think you already done best

Comment: its not working though.

Comment: Probably because `$(this '.col-1')` isn't a valid selector. Presumably you mean `$('.col1', this).on('change', fn)` and `$(this).val()` within the handler itself - although it's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do here without seeing the accompanying HTML

Comment: share html as well in a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```js
 $( ".container .col-1" ).on( "keyup",this,function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.col-1').not($(this)).val(value);
});
```

```css
.col-1 {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.container {
 max-width:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block
}
.container p {
 text-align:center;
 font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<p>Enter some text</p>
<textarea class="col-1"></textarea>
<hr>
<textarea class="col-1"></textarea>
<textarea class="col-1"></textarea>
<textarea class="col-1"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Once I've ascertained whether this is your desired output, I'll then add some additional explanation

Comment: Does not work for some reason. The `$(this).val();` is empty on keyup. but in stacoverflow its fine.  I cahnged it to `var value = e.target.textContent;` which get the changed value. But it doe not apply it. Could it be a JQuery version issue?

Comment: If it works here, then it works. If it don't work when you copy it into your code then that's something on *your* side that's breaking it

Comment: Obviously, you need to make sure you have the correct selectors for your html. I doubt you have exactly the same layout as I put here

Comment: Its only the `$('.col-1').not($(this)).val(value);` thats not working. the rest is fine. The only difference is I have a ID foe each aswell. and I use `<div contenteditable>` which apparently mimics a textarea.

Comment: Does it work in the 'run code snippet' in my answer?

Comment: Solution - `$('.col-1').not($(this)).text(value);`

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a `<textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code might help you.

```
$('.col-1').on('change', function(){
var value = $(this).val();
    $('.col-1').each(function (){
$(this).val(value);
}
})
```